# Android List Views

Tags: android

I am using View pager and pager Adapter for user swipes.My requirement is,I have three list view i.e 0,1,2. At first launched I need to display 1st list view i.e index position 1 .When a user swipes the left I have to display 40% of 0 index postion List view and  60% of second index position 1 list View(In the same view),When a user swipes the right I have  to display 50% of index postion 1 list View and 50% of index position 2 List View(In the same view).For the past few days I am struggling how to get this.Please give me a solution to solve this problem.

My Code is

```
private Context mContext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listview1 = new ListView(mContext);
    ListView listview2 = new ListView(mContext);
    ListView listview3 = new ListView(mContext);

    Vector<View> pages = new Vector<View>();

    pages.add(listview1);
    pages.add(listview2);
    pages.add(listview3);

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(mContext,pages);
    vp.setAdapter(adapter);
    vp.setCurrentItem(1);
     listview1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new String[]{"A1","B1","C1","D1"}));
    listview2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new String[]{"A2","B2","C2","D2"}));
    listview3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new String[]{"A3","B3","C3","D3"}));
    }
```

## CustomPagerAdapter

public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
    private Context mContext;
    private Vector<View> pages;
    View page;
    int i=0;
    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, Vector<View> pages) {
         this.mContext=context;
         this.pages=pages;
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
         page = pages.get(position);
            container.addView(page);
         Log.i("venkat2", "is" + position);
         //position=position * 2;
         return page;
    }
            @Override
    public int getCount() {
            return pages.size();
            }
            @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        //Log.i("venkat3", "is" + "3");
         container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        //Log.i("venkat4", "is" + "4");
          return view.equals(object);
    }
```

Thanks & Regards,
Venkatesan.R

Comment: I don't understand your problem. ViewPager manage the swipe by itself so why bother ?

Comment: can you post  a wire-frame of your requirement so that it would easy for us.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your kind reply.I am working on Calendar with gridview ,Rightnow I have implemented gesture listener for left and right swipe,All are working fine , But using onsingletapconfirmed i could not able to get the position of the selected item in the griview. It remains position 0 on all selected item in the Gridview.I tried with the below code

int j = gridview.pointToPosition((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());

Please help to me solve the problem.